# Powershell - Create a basic JSON file

Tags: json, powershell

Newbie to JSON and need some help creating a basic JSON file.  Here's the basic code:

```
$fruits = lookup-fruit | ConvertFrom-Json
foreach ($fruit in $fruits) {
   $fruit.name
   $fruit.color
   $fruit.origin
}
```

I need to take the above and create a JSON file with the following format:

```
[
  {
   "Fruit Name": "Apple",
   "Color": "Red",
   "Origin": "Oregon"
  },
  {
   "Fruit Name": "Orange",
   "Color": "Orange",
   "Origin": "Florida"
  }
]
```

Any guidance is appreciated.  Thanks in advance.

Comment: What is your source (file)? (Please add to the question)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try this and see if it's what you want.

```
$apple=@{ "Fruit Name"="Apple"; Color="Red"; Origin="Oregon"; Quantity=10; Price=7.00 }
$orange=@{ "Fruit Name"="Orange"; Color="Orange"; Origin="Florida"; Quantity=4; Price=2.00 }
$fruits=@($apple, $orange)

$json=ConvertTo-Json -InputObject $fruits
$json
[
    {
        "Price":  7,
        "Color":  "Red",
        "Quantity":  10,
        "Origin":  "Oregon",
        "Fruit Name":  "Apple"
    },
    {
        "Price":  2,
        "Color":  "Orange",
        "Quantity":  4,
        "Origin":  "Florida",
        "Fruit Name":  "Orange"
    }
]
```

Comment: Thanks Bruceline.  That works. Instead of created the array manually, can you show example of how to create it inside the foreach statement?  Thanks

Comment: I'm so sorry, but I don't understand exactly what you mean.
In principle, as long as the source data is structured data, it can be solved in this way. Can you describe how your source data comes from?

Comment: I think I get it now.  Thanks